# Get list items by group by sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint-2013

I have a library and I was already get items by view name use ajax call Rest api. Now, I want to get items by group by. How can I do?

Thank you

below is my code

```
function getListItems(webUrl, listTitle, queryText, webpartId) {

        var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';


        var queryPayload = {

            'query': {

                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },

                'ViewXml': viewXml

            }

        };

      $.ajax({

            url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle +"')/
       getitems?$select=Title,FileLeafRef",

            method: "POST",

            data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),

            headers: {

                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),

                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",

                "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"

            },

            success: function(itemsdata){

                var items = itemsdata.d.results;

                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

             strHtml += '<li class="b"><a href=' + items[i].FileLeafRef + '>' + items[i].Title + '</a></li>';

                }

                $(tbl).append(strHtml);
            }

        });
    }
```

please help me

Comment: Please post any coding attempt you have made.

Comment: i did have links you can see

Comment: That is not how it works. Post the code as text.

Comment: I did show the code

Comment: I think you get get by view

Comment: now I want to get by group by in this view

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `queryText` (if you aren't already doing this) and use `<GorupBy>` in your CAML query e.g. to group by *Title* column

```
<Query>
  <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE">
     <FieldRef Name="Title" />
  </GroupBy>
</Query>
```

Comment: but it only group by but not in specific View name.

Comment: you can create a CAML query with conditions same as you've applied in your view, it doesn't seem to be possible to grab a view via REST